# problem with passing booleans to update_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, update-attributes

I've got the following Model:

```
class GuestCatering < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Validation
  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates :order_number, :presence => true
  validates :orderable, :presence => true

end
```

But when I'll try to update an existing GuestCatering with the following code:

```
guest_catering.update_attributes(:orderable => false)
```

The guest catering variable is a valid GuestCatering object.
The guest_catering object has errors after the update, like that:

```
<{[:orderable, ["can't be blank"]]=>nil}>
```

But when i pass a `orderable => true`, everything is fine and no errors.

What's wrong here, why can't i set orderable to false?

Comment: Try this: guest_catering.update_attributes(:orderable => 0)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Your model is actually behaving exactly as you told it to, through your use of `validates :orderable, :presence => true`

There's little point validating the presence of a boolean flag - it's going to be `true`, `nil` or `false` - and in Ruby world, nil and false have the same semantic value when it comes to boolean logic.

Internally, `validates :presence` relies on the value of the attribute being checked to return `false` when `blank?` is called. And, in Rails (with ActiveSupport), `false.blank?` evaluates as `true` - which means that your field is failing the validation.

Simply remove that validation and everything will work as expected.

Comment: So I can't validate a boolean flag?

Comment: How would you validate it? It's either on or off. If you _need_ it to be true (such as agreeing to terms), then you could use a validation to enforce it. In your case, it doesn't appear to be required.

Comment: Thanks this helped me out a lot i was in a similar predicament

Answer (score 21):

Like Dan Cheail already said in his answer, a `nil` and `false` boolean is semantically the same thing.

But, if you really need to validate it (not allowing `nil`), you can always do :

`validates_inclusion_of :orderable, :in => [true, false]`

Comment: If your database column for your boolean is `NOT NULL`, this is the correct answer as this will validate the field before attempting to write the record. The other answer will allow the validation to pass with `nil`, but `.save` will error on the column restriction.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of `validates :presence => :true`, you should write your migrations with the default value like this:

```
t.boolean :orderable, :default => 0
```

I assume your default value should be `false`. If `true`, use 1 as default. Then it will set the default value in database. So, you can omit the validation check.

The reason you cannot use `validates :presence` is answered by @dan. Presence means not blank and Rails use `.blank?` function for this and `false.blank?` is `true`